# Generate a xml from a html

Tags: html, xml

Im trying to generate a xml from a html (url). The html website have a formulary that i want to get into a xml archive, but its too long and im searching a way to do it easier.

There is a method to generate a xml with all the fields, etc, from a html?

Answer (score 1):

you can also use an html parser and print out the objects / array as xml

try this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/html2xml/

Comment: @Daneil Ruf this doesnt work. It make an error when i try to extract the xml from the html

Comment: maybe you have to fix some tags  http://www.xmlwrench.com/manual/convert.html    well there are many html to xml converters around in the web, dont know what you exactly want to do (online converter, windows programm, php script?)

Comment: i want to convert an html of a online web to an xml with all the fields that appear in the html. I think that is online converter :l

Answer (score 0):

You can try the free dotnet-classlibrary [SgmlReader](http://developer.mindtouch.com/en/docs/SgmlReader) that can load html into a xmldocument. This in turn can be saved as xml.